# Animation loop how to stop it?

Tags: animation, lua, roblox

Hi i am making a tower defense game and the animation for the towers attack keeps looping.
This here is the code: (not the entire code)

```
function Tower.Attack(newTower)
    local target = FindNearestTarget(newTower)
    if target then
animateTowerEvent:FireAllClients(newTower, "Attack")
target.Humanoid:TakeDamage(40)
end

task.wait(1)

Tower.Attack(newTower)
end
```

here is the animation script:

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local events = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Events")
local animateTowerEvent = events:WaitForChild("AnimateTower")

local function SetAnimation(object, animName)
    local humanoid = object:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    local animationsFolder = object:WaitForChild("Animations")
    if humanoid and animationsFolder then
        local animationObject = animationsFolder:WaitForChild(animName)
        if animationObject then
            local animator = humanoid:FindFirstChild("Animator")
            local animationTrack = animator:LoadAnimation(animationObject)
            return animationTrack
        end
    end
end
local function playAnimation(object, animName)
    local animationTrack = SetAnimation(object, animName)
    if animationTrack then
        animationTrack:Play()
    else
        warn("Animation track does not exist")
        return
    end
end

workspace.Mobs.ChildAdded:Connect(function(object)
    playAnimation(object, "Walk")
workspace.Towers.ChildAdded:Connect(function(object)
    playAnimation(object, "Idle")
end)
animateTowerEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(tower, animName)
    playAnimation(tower, animName)
end)
```

i relly hope the local script helps

Comment: Where are you actually playing the animation? Is it in the handler for `animateTowerEvent` on the client side?

Comment: i play it in a Local Script that is connected with it

Comment: Can you edit your post to include that LocalScript then? It seems like that's where the problem would be.

Comment: its inclueded now

Answer (score 1):

The [`Looped`](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/AnimationTrack/Looped) property for your `AnimationTrack` was probably set to `true` when you created it in the animation editor. You could prevent the animation from looping in one of two ways:

1. Edit the `Looped` property in the animation editor and update the animation.
2. Set the `Looped` property to `false` in your `SetAnimation` function:

```
local function SetAnimation(object, animName)
    local humanoid = object:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    local animationsFolder = object:WaitForChild("Animations")
    if humanoid and animationsFolder then
        local animationObject = animationsFolder:WaitForChild(animName)
        if animationObject then
            local animator = humanoid:FindFirstChild("Animator")
            local animationTrack = animator:LoadAnimation(animationObject)
            animationTrack.Looped = false
            return animationTrack
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: How do i edit the loop property?

Comment: @Denhemmelige2 You should be able to with the corresponding button in the Animation Editor (https://i.imgur.com/K9vKDYt.png). If you're not able to do it there, you can also just set the property in your script, which will achieve the same effect.

Comment: when i check the animation the looping is turned off

Comment: I would try forcibly setting the property in your script as I described above then.

Comment: but then my walk animations will not loop

Comment: i just woke up and its working